# Using images from one class in another?

Tags: java, image, class, variables, loading

i was wondering if it would be possible to have one central class just for images. **Also, how would i use an image from one class in another?** I couldn't find the answer to this at all, on other sites. I'm sorry for this dumb question, but i'm fairly new to programming, and the loading of images and sprite animations is what frustrates me the most, and i won't be able to advance to anything else, unless i get these kinds of problems out my head! Thank you for everyone that helps!

Comment: An image (once it's loaded from disk) is an object.  Any other object that is capable of storing object pointers (which is pretty much all of them) can "contain" image objects.

Comment: @HotLicks   Thanks, for that info! I'm sorry, but i just realised that i have to redo my title since it is a bit confusing. Thanks for

Comment: 1) Get the address of the image.  2) Use it.

Comment: Keep in mind that there are a hundred (at least) different ways that an "image" can be "in a class" in Java.  You're not going to get anything at all specific as an answer unless you ask a specific question about a specific set of circumstances with a specific GUI toolkit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a new object in clasee and using this object to invoke the function
also you can set class as static class

Comment: So to use images from my main image class, would i make a new instance of the class in the other class, or would i make a new instance of the image? I am so confused, and i very sorry for my stupidity.